# SSL. no OPENSSL_Applink

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

There are openssl server and Qt client using QSslSocket.
When client connected to server server shows no OPENSSL_Applink and shuts down. But with OpenSSL client server works correct. What can be a reason?

Comment: Any logs/messages on a client side?

Comment: Solved by including applink.c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#include <openssl/applink.c>
```

Including `applink.c` will solve the problem. Please check [OpenSSL FAQ](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html)

Basically we get this error only if we use any file handling APIs like `d2i_X509`. I was getting assert failure in `applink.c` while using this API in windows VC8.0. Later I have done fopen separately and called `d2i_X509_fp` API.

Comment: It seems one should add this line in a source file rather than a header file.