# Python Quickfix-SSL Error: OPENSSL_Uplink: no OPENSSL_Applink

Tags: python, c++, quickfix

I am trying to use [quickfix-ssl](https://pypi.org/project/quickfix-ssl/) which exposes the SSLSocketInitiator/Acceptor capabilities currently unsupported in quickfix. Unfortunately there are no pre-compiled .whls for windows os so having to compile from source. I've had to modify "setup.py" as the current config was linux-oriented.

After solving several compiler link errors, I have managed to compile and install the resulting .whl. However, when I attempt to run the application, specifically, `SSLSocketAcceptor()` I get the error "OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFAC47C2AC8,08): no OPENSSL_Applink".

In an attempt to solve the issue I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125905/ssl-no-openssl-applink) and added to the "UtilitySSL.cpp" source file and rebuilt but the issue persists, so now I am completely at a loss. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Python Version: 3.7
SSL Version: 1.1.1g
OpenSSL Version (from VCPKG): 3.1.4.

"setup.py" code:

```
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

import glob
import sys
import sysconfig

_VCPKG_ROOT = r"C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows"
_VCPKG_ROOT_POSIX = "/src/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows"
_WIN_SDK_ROOT = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10"


VCPKG_INCLUDE = _VCPKG_ROOT + r'\include'
VCPKG_EXTRA_LIBS = [
    _VCPKG_ROOT + r"\lib\libssl.lib",
    _VCPKG_ROOT + r"\lib\libcrypto.lib",
    #_VCPKG_ROOT + r"\lib\Ws2_32.lib",
]

WIN_EXTRA_LIBS = [
     _WIN_SDK_ROOT + r"\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64\WS2_32.lib"
]

VCPKG_DLL_DEPENDENCIES = [
    _VCPKG_ROOT + r"\bin\libcrypto-3-x64.dll",
    _VCPKG_ROOT + r"\bin\libssl-3-x64.dll",
]

#OPEN_SSL_DLL_DEPS = [
#    r"C:\src\openssl-1.1.1w-win64\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll",
#    r"C:\src\openssl-1.1.1w-win64\libssl-1_1-x64.dll",
#]


#r"C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"
#r"C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\libssl.lib",
#r"C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\libcrypto.lib",
#r"C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\Ws2_32.lib"

class build_ext_subclass(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        self.compiler.define_macro("PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION", sys.version_info[0])
        print("Testing for std::tr1::shared_ptr...")
        try:
            self.compiler.compile(['test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp'])
            self.compiler.define_macro("HAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR")
            print("...found")
        except:
            print(" ...not found")

        print("Testing for std::shared_ptr...")
        try:
            self.compiler.compile(['test_std_shared_ptr.cpp'], extra_preargs=['/std:c++14']),
            self.compiler.define_macro("HAVE_STD_SHARED_PTR")
            print("...found")
        except:
            print("...not found")

        print("Testing for std::unique_ptr...")
        try:
            self.compiler.compile(['test_std_unique_ptr.cpp'], extra_preargs=['/std:c++14']),
            self.compiler.define_macro("HAVE_STD_UNIQUE_PTR")
            print("...found")
        except:
            print("...not found")

        build_ext.build_extensions(self)


# Remove the "-Wstrict-prototypes" compiler option, which isn't valid for C++.
cfg_vars = sysconfig.get_config_vars()
for key, value in cfg_vars.items():
    if type(value) == str:
        cfg_vars[key] = value.replace("-Wstrict-prototypes", "")

# DDLs to be moved to "Lib/site-packages" in your current environment 
dll_files = [('Lib/site-packages', [filepath]) for filepath in VCPKG_DLL_DEPENDENCIES]
#dll_files = [('Lib/site-packages', [filepath]) for filepath in OPEN_SSL_DLL_DEPS]

ext = Extension(
    '_quickfix',
    glob.glob('C++/*.cpp'),
    include_dirs=["C++", VCPKG_INCLUDE],
    #define_macros=[("HAVE_SSL", "1"), ("_MSC_VER", 1936)],
    #define_macros=[("HAVE_SSL", "1")],
    define_macros=[("HAVE_SSL", "1"), ("__cplusplus", "1")],
    extra_compile_args=[
        '/std:c++14',
        #'-W-deprecated',
        #'-W-unused-variable',
        #'-W-deprecated-declarations',
        #'-W-maybe-uninitialized'
    ],
    #extra_link_args=[
    #    "-lssl"
    #],
    extra_objects=VCPKG_EXTRA_LIBS + WIN_EXTRA_LIBS
)

with open("README.md") as f:
    long_desc=f.read()

setup(name='quickfix-ssl',
      version='1.15.1-4',
      py_modules=[
          'quickfix', 'quickfixt11', 'quickfix40', 'quickfix41', 'quickfix42',
          'quickfix43', 'quickfix44', 'quickfix50', 'quickfix50sp1', 'quickfix50sp2'
      ],
      data_files=[('share/quickfix', glob.glob('spec/FIX*.xml'))] + dll_files,
      author='Oren Miller',
      author_email='oren@quickfixengine.org',
      maintainer='Mark Lee',
      maintainer_email='mark.lee@droveend.com',
      description="FIX (Financial Information eXchange) protocol implementation (SSL enabled)",
      long_description=long_desc,
      long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
      url='http://www.quickfixengine.org',
      download_url='http://www.quickfixengine.org',
      license_files=('LICENSE',),
      cmdclass = {
          'build_ext': build_ext_subclass
      },
      ext_modules=[ext]
)
```